# Don't want spaces in the text, but this regex is passing not sure why

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I am using the following regex

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/i.test(value)
```

If I enter a space in the word, it passes.

I don't see where spaces are aloud in the regex, why is it passing?

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the beginning and end bounderies so that the entire string must match the regular expression, otherwise it'll look for any match (which in this case is one or more of the characters specified).

Try this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/i.test(value)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you haven't anchored it.

For these sorts of tests, it's typically safer to make sure you *don't* have the negated character class:

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/
```

Comment: don't or do?  isn't the ^ the negated symbol?

Comment: yes, ^ negates the character class -- but you need to flip the sense of the test (if ! (bad characters)) vs. (if (good characters)).